# Using a variable to open a text file in Python

Tags: python, variables, tile

Is it possible to use a variable (such as username) to open a text file that is named based on that variable. For example, in the following program, the file is called "Username1", and I want it to append details to it, IF it exists. In the below situation, I am using the actual username (username1), but I want it to be able to insert the username (which is a variable) there instead.

```
#Open Writer to append to file
with open("username1.txt","a") as membersfile:
    membersfileWriter=csv.writer(membersfile)
    membersfileWriter.writerow([viewedlist])
```

THe username, in this program is passed to this particular function as a parameter:

```
def viewfilmfunction(x,username):
```

Comment: `username+".txt"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
username = 'username1' # This can be passed in as your function arg.
with open("%s.txt" % username,"a") as membersfile:
  membersfileWriter=csv.writer(membersfile)
  membersfileWriter.writerow([viewedlist])
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: if you wanted to write, and by that I mean CREATE a completely new file based on a username, would it simply be "w" instead of "a"? ...I'm not sure of this syntax

Answer (score 1):

```
username = "placeholder"
with open('{}.txt'.format(username), 'a') as memberfile:
    ...
```